# Value from an IF Statement then SUM Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

hopefully this is a quick fix.

I have two columns of data, column A1 already populated and column B2, which will be populated ad hoc, then based on whether there is data in either cell, carry out a calculation (E3*D3)then multiplied by the value of the cell either A1 or B2.

So I am fine with the basic IF statements below, and can combine them using IF(OR, but I am stuck using an IF to look at B2 is it greater or less than A1, but doesn't equal 0, then use that value as part of a multiplication (E3*D3)*value ? 
Is this possible?

Examples

```
=IF(B3=0,(SUM(E3*D3)*A3))
=IF(B2=A2,(SUM(E2*D2)*B2))
```

[image: Excel Example]

I hope I have made some form of sense, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: why are you doing `SUM(E3*D3)`?

Comment: I would to multiple rack length E3 by Lanes D3, then multiple the value of either A1 or B2 to get 2 hours stock

Comment: No I am asking why do you have SUM(E3*D3)? Because that is the same as E3*D3

Comment: I am getting confused with your references, which do not match your picture.  How can you multiply A1 which is a string `Pack 1` with a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
=IF(AND(B3<>0, B3<>A3), E3*D3*B3, E3*D3*A3)
```